# Adding day to NSDate when a day doesn't equal 24 hours - iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsdate, ios5, dst

I want to add a day to a NSDate object if its in the past (for an Alarm).  However I ran into a problem if I just add 60*60*24 seconds. It adds 24 hours like what is usually wanted but in this case a day equals 23 hours.  How do I fix this? Here is the following code:

```
 while ([alarmTime compare:[[NSDate alloc] init]] == NSOrderedAscending) {
        alarmTime = [alarmTime dateByAddingTimeInterval:(60*60*24)]; //if in the past add a day
        NSLog(@"alarm %@ is in the past, adding a day", alarmTime);
    }
```

---

```
22:19:59.506: alarm 03/12/2011 12:00:00 AM is in the past, adding a day
22:19:59.506: alarm 03/13/2011 12:00:00 AM is in the past, adding a day
22:19:59.507: alarm 03/14/2011 01:00:00 AM is in the past, adding a day
22:19:59.507: alarm 03/15/2011 01:00:00 AM is in the past, adding a day
```

Comment: Not related to your question directly, but you have a huge memory leak there. Create an NSDate variable using [NSDate date] and use that for your comparisons.

Comment: It bugged me, too. But I guess with ARC that's not a leak anymore. This will take some getting used to...

Comment: @nschum - even if it's not a leak, it's a waste of resources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code I am now using that corrects this issue:

---

```
-(void) correctDate {        
    // Create an interval of one day
    NSDateComponents *dayComponent = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    dayComponent.day = 1;

    NSCalendar *theCalendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];

    // if its in the past, add  day
    while ([alarmTime compare:[NSDate date]] == NSOrderedAscending) {
        alarmTime = [theCalendar dateByAddingComponents:dayComponent toDate:alarmTime options:0];  //add a day

        NSLog(@"alarm %@ is in the past, adding a day", alarmTime);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This isn't a bug, it is how NSDate's `description` method formats the date for your logging. Remember, NSDate just stores a time interval since a reference date, so adding a days worth of seconds will always increase it by a day. In your time zone, daylight savings time begins on 13 march, so 24 hours after midnight on the day before *is* 1 am.

Regarding your comment of how to fix this, what do you want to fix? The code in your question will add 24 hours to `alarmTime` until `alarmTime` is in the future. If your requirement is actually that the user enters, say, 5am, and you want `alarmTime` to be the *next* 5am, then this isn't really the way to go about it, you'd be better off synthesising a new date using `NSDateComponents`.